# Trying to strip Sidebar Login code down to just log out (wordpress / woocommerce)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, logout, woocommerce

I'm quite the php novice, but I'm trying to slay this dragon as if i'm not.

My wordpress/woocommerce site is going to be used as a store, but there's a bug preventing a simple solution to log out as a customer (not a meta logout - just a shop/user level logout).

I'm trying to repurpose this code http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/ to simply display a "Log Out" when someone is logged in and display nothing when a user is logged out.

[Sidebar Login is on github here.][1]

[1]: https://github.com/mikejolley/sidebar-login Thanks for any assistance anyone might provide.

Answer (score 0):

Under sidebar-login/includes/class-sidebar-login-widget.php

https://github.com/mikejolley/sidebar-login/blob/master/includes/class-sidebar-login-widget.php#L239-L284

Replace Line: 239 - 284

with this:

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $logged_in_title = $this->replace_tags( apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_logged_in_title', $logged_in_title ) );

        if ( $logged_in_title )
            echo $before_title . $logged_in_title . $after_title;

        do_action( 'sidebar_login_widget_logged_in_content_start' );

        if ( $show_avatar == 1 )
            echo '<div class="avatar_container">' . get_avatar( $this->user->ID, apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_avatar_size', 38 ) ) . '</div>';

        echo '<ul class="pagenav sidebar_login_links"><li class="logout-link"><a href="'. wp_logout_url(home_url()) .'">Logout</a></li></ul>';

        do_action( 'sidebar_login_widget_logged_in_content_end' );

    // Logged out user
    } else {}
```